# spring oauth2 authorize flow in single page app

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I am implementing an oauth2 authorization server for providing access to our apis.
Our application is a single page application, with the a jwt token in the authentication header to provide access.
We want to setup an oauth2 Authorization Code flow like,

1. User is on external site and wants to get access to our apis
2. External site redirects to our site/spa with oauth2 params, client_id etc.
3. SPA checks authentication, users needs to login to continue
4. User sees page for confirming access
5. User confirms access, code is returned and redirected to external site
6. External site does backchannel call to obtain token from code

My problem is in 4 and 5, in standard Spring setup this is provided by
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint, 
on /oauth/authorize GET oauth params are stored in the session and the confirmation page is shown, and on post of that the code is returned in the redirect.

But I cannot find any guidance/examples on how to do this with a page hosted in a SPA.
You have to be authenticated in this endpoint and I cannot really use the top level page that /oauth/authorized provides because we use header based authentication on rest api calls only, all our top level calls are unauthenticated.

Is there some obvious way to make this work?
I think I do not want to put my authentication token in a cookie. 
I was thinking of just then creating a controller that sort of does what the AuthorizationEndpoint does and returning a redirect to the redirect in Javascript. But I am not sure if I would be breaking some other security requirement.

Comment: why is that? I could also keep the oauth parameters in the client app, show an approval page and then on approval post to a controller that would return the redirect url. The only problem is how to create that controller then. I did not find and api/service yet that provides a code based on these input params. But in theory that would be all I need.

Comment: OAuth2 security is based on authorization server, hence authentication and authorization should happen on authorization site. If you show some SPA site instead, then it is not trusted. The SPA should not be able to change the approval of the user.

Comment: the SPA site is our main application handling all authentication with a token in the header. So you are saying you can never combine this with a correct oauth2 flow?

Comment: No, I didn't. Your authorization server needs sessions for login page and for approval page. But your resource server could use a stateless communication without sessions.

Comment: The users will already be authenticated by a front controlling app. This one manages the login page. Then requests are proxied by zuul in that app to the authorisation server, with the authorisation passed as a token in the header. I think I could add sessions to the authorisation server, but I am not sure how to mix this header based authorisation with the session based that the top level oauth/authorize pages need.

Comment: *The users will already be authenticated by a front controlling app.* That is not OAuth2. The authorization server does the authentication.

Comment: However, you could try to change the authorization server configuration to use your token instead of username and password of its login page. But you could get some problems like CORS.

Comment: I could move the authorisation server into the front controlling app then it does the authentication. But still that would leave me with the same problem I think.

Comment: Controlling app is a web app or a client app? You could use a custom login page for your authorization server, that's no problem. Then your session is working and the approval page is shown.

Comment: the controlling app is a spring boot web app. I could create a custom login page, but then i guess it would not be single sign on anymore, but maybe that is fine.

Comment: might be even better/more secure to not reuse that session, then the challenge would become how would I reuse the accounts/configuration of the front controlling app in the authentication server.

Comment: Why is it not SSO? Where do you login? If your controlling app is a Spring Boot application, all you need is to add a authorization server configuration to that app. Then your controlling app is also an authorization server. Then you could use your login page.